# Allow local HTML files' scripts to load other local files

Tags: macos, safari, monterey

How can I tell Safari that I would like the JavaScript included in local HTML files to be allowed to load other local files?

At the moment:

- I double-click `index.html` in Finder
- it opens an HTML page in Safari (url is `file:///...`)
- it runs a JavaScript that requests another relative file (e.g.

  ```
    (new XMLHttpRequest()).open('GET', './data.json')
  ```
- console is full of "cannot load [file:///.../index.js](//) due to access control checks" etc. errors

I know I can start a static webserver in the HTML file's directory to work around this, but it would be convenient if I can configure Safari to allow the HTML/JS initially opened off of my local file system to be able to import other local files.

Comment: Is it just JavaScript? As far as I can tell, Safari works with local pages fine; except when it re-launches and tries to open 'existing' documents from the last session, which flags an error. As usual, it's probably Security.

Comment: @benwiggy thanks for prompting me to do some deeper checking. Actually, Safari only seems to block JavaScript from loading local files. Stuff included directly via the HTML seems to be loaded fine.

Comment: Definitely yet another 'security feature'...